# JSON- LD code can't parse while Minify the code

Tags: json, json-ld

The code works very well in goggle webmaster tool. But when I try to minify the JSON-ld code. This error throws up every time.

Error code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
Error: Unexpected token <
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "How are you doing?",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "text": "I'm doing great :)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Can you please help me out?

Thanks 
Suresh

Comment: I have pasted the code below the image, now I removed it.. so that I only added the error code. Thanks rob.

Comment: What are you using to do the minification? I suspect your issue is that it only minifies json-ld. While your supplying it html (the script tags)

Comment: Tony, I did try every tool online to minify, but can't able to minify it. I got the code from here.. He can able to minify but using online tools I can't able to minify at all. 

https://saijogeorge.com/json-ld-schema-generator/faq/

Comment: Can you name one tool that fails?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did tried minifying with this too https://jsonformatter.org